# How do I fix the error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' "

Tags: c#, winforms, class, constructor

I have a class EngineerClass that inherits values from another class (EmployeeClass).

I want the Windows form to use values from the other class and display them in text boxes. When trying to call the EngineerClass in the Form Class, I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
class EngineerClass : EmployeeClass
{    
    private int trafficHours;

    public int TrafficHours
    {
        set { trafficHours = value; }
        get { return trafficHours; }
    }

    public EngineerClass(String name, int id, int pay, int wh) : base(name, id, pay, wh)
    {
        trafficHours = 0;
    }

    public void addTrafficHours(int tH)
    {
        trafficHours = tH;
        workedHours += trafficHours;
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class frmEngineer : Form
{
    private EngineerClass Class = new EngineerClass();
    public frmEngineer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `public EngineerClass(String name, int id, int pay, int wh)` Your `new EngineerClass()` code must include **all four** of those parameters. If you don't want to do that, you need to add a parameterless constructor to `EngineerClass`.

Comment: While we're looking at your code: **do not name things according to what they are in the program**. That should be `class Employee` not `class EmployeeClass`. Do not use abbrvs when making compounds: `fmrEngineer` should be `EngineerForm`. Your code will be easier to read, understand and debug when you follow standard conventions.

Comment: Also, any time you see an `int` field whose name indicates a time period like `Hours`, something is probably wrong. Why is that `int` and not an appropriate type such as `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You require four things to make an engineer:

```
public EngineerClass(String name, int id, int pay, int wh)
```

The things "name", "id", and so on are *formal parameters*. They are *required*.

You have provided zero things:

```
private EngineerClass Class = new EngineerClass();
```

The things you provide that correspond to formals are called *arguments*.

One of the things you did not provide was argument corresponding to the name, hence the error: "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' "

> How do I fix it?

Either

- Supply the arguments for the required formal parameters, or
- Make them *optional* formal parameters, or
- Make a second constructor that takes zero formal parameters

Remember that whatever you do, your derived class is *required* to meet the *requirements* of its base class constructor.